# What is the regional language of Absalom?

Tags: character-creation, pathfinder-2e, languages, pathfinder-society

This is a question specifically about Pathfinder Society (Second Edition) Characters.

If you create a Pathfinder Society Character, you get Common (Taldan) as starting language as well as access to the regional language of the region / country / area your character hails from.
Regional Languages are listed here:
[Regional Languages](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=132)

What regional language do you gain access to if your character grew up in Absalom? The wording

> Nearly every language listed here is spoken on the melting-pot streets of Absalom.

suggests that you can actually chose every regional language as "your" regional language, but I can't find any other information about this except this short sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absalom doesn't have an specific regional language, but every regional language is prevalent in the region, as indicated in the [regional languages](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=132) section, and in the World Guide handbook on page 12.

This means you get **access** to all of them if you hail from there. Still, you don't automatically gain the regional language(s) of a region just because you grew up in it, you need to spend one of your additional languages from a high intelligence score to learn it (or learn it via other sources like the [Multilingual](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=814) feat).

Furthermore, this question is specifically addressed in the official [Pathfinder Society FAQ](https://paizo.com/pathfindersociety/faq#what-languages-do-PCs-from-absalom-have-access-to):

> What languages do characters from Absalom have access to?
>
> Characters from Absalom have access to Erutaki, Hallit, Kelish, Mwangi, Osiriani, Shoanti, Skald, Tien, Varki, Varisian, and Vudrani.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that you only gain access to, but not automatically gain your regional language(s). I edited my original question so there is no confusion for future readers.